# writing join query query in zf2 and Doctrine2

Tags: php, sql, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I have a query in zf2 and doctrine orm. I am joining the result of two queries on the same table by its primary_key.

It seems, I am making a syntax error and not able to find out.

```
$query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery(
    "select tc_result1.id as id ,tc_result1.displayId as displayId,tc_result1.activeFlag,tc_result1.hash
        from
        (
            SELECT *
            FROM (
                    SELECT id, display_id,active_flag,hash
                    FROM Test\Entity\TestCase tc_inner1
                    where tc_inner1.activeFlag=0 and tc_inner1.product = :productId
                    ORDER BY tc_inner1.displayId DESC
                 ) a
            GROUP BY hash 
        ) AS tc_result1

        join

        (
            SELECT *
            FROM (
                    SELECT id, displayId,activeFlag,hash
                    FROM Test\Entity\TestCase tc_inner2
                    where tc_inner2.activeFlag=0 and tc_inner2.product = :productId
                    ORDER BY tc_inner2.displayId DESC
                 ) a
            GROUP BY hash 
        ) AS tc_result2
        on
        tc_result1.id = tc_result2.id"
   );
$query->setParameter("productId", $productId);
```

I got following error:

> Additional information: Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException File:
>       /var/www/test-suite/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/QueryException.php:63
>
> Message:
>
> ```
> [Semantical Error] line 0, col 153 near '(': Error: Class '(' is not defined.
> ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer I gave to a similar question yesterday on the [doctrine-user mailinglist](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/doctrine-user/Xn_NcNeaN_Y/discussion) is also applicable here:

> What you are doing **wrong** here is: **defining an ON-clause**. That
>   is how you'd do it in SQL. In DQL however you define the relationship
>   between your entities in the *mapping*-information (via annotations,
>   xml, yaml or php) and in the query you use that relationship. So:
>   define a OneToOne, OneToMany, ManyToOne or ManyToMany relationship and
>   use that in the query (and consequently no need to use a ON).

And related (from the same thread):

> you are not querying the tables with DQL, but the entities! The
>   entities (objects) form a network, the object graph. You can "walk"
>   that graph. The associations are not defined in the query (with ON or
>   WHERE), but in the mapping. That is the whole point of an ORM;
>   otherwise there is no need to use it and you could better just
>   directly query the database with SQL.

Answer (score 1):

I got the problem. Doctrine queries to Entity class rather than the table. It expects an entity class after

```
select tc_result1.id as id ,tc_result1.displayId as displayId,tc_result1.activeFlag,tc_result1.hash
                from
                (
```

A solution to this problem is using **[ResultSetMappingBuilder](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html#resultsetmappingbuilder)** object , using which we can write the query in native sql and map the result to doctrine object